# Mamp mysql in ZSH

Tags: terminal, zsh

Do I have to use /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -uroot -p to access mamps Mysql through the terminal?

or

is there an easier way? I'm using ITERM and ZSH not the actual bash and terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add "/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/" to your $PATH. How to do this depends on your zsh configuration, but in general, you should be able to edit the file ".zshrc" in your home directory, and add something like this:

```
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/:$PATH"
```

Restart your terminal for the changes to take effect.